# Check individual element of an array with another array in php

Tags: php

I have two array name position and data respectively.

```
$position = array("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","B1","B2","B3","B4","B5");
Array ( [0] => B1 [1] => B2 [2] => A2 [3] => A3 )
```

this second array named data which are coming from mysql database.Now i need to check the element of data array in position array.I tried this code

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) { if ($i==5){?>
  <br> <?php } ?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="pos[]" value="<?php echo $position[$i];?>"
  <?php if(in_array($data[$i], $position)) echo "checked";
   ?>>
  <label ><?php echo $position[$i] ?></label>
<?php }
```

and i get the result is

A1   A2   A3   A4

> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in G:\xampp\htdocs\library\ajax.php on line 25 A5
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in G:\xampp\htdocs\library\ajax.php on line 25 B1
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in G:\xampp\htdocs\library\ajax.php on line 25 B2
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in G:\xampp\htdocs\library\ajax.php on line 25 B3
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in G:\xampp\htdocs\library\ajax.php on line 25 B4
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in G:\xampp\htdocs\library\ajax.php on line 25 B5

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just change `<?php if(in_array($position[$i], $data)) echo "checked";`

Comment: @splash58 Thanks